# I want to draw a line but change some things and use a class to keep drawing new lines

Tags: python, windows, function, methods, pyglet

So I wanted to make a program that would draw a line from your current cursor position to the closest ball to it.. The line keeps glitching and I am at a loss of ideas of how to draw the line so it is a clear looking line

This is the code:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=1900, height=1050, fullscreen=False, caption="Dots", resizable=True, vsync=True)


class DrawLines:
    coordinates = [0, 0]
    color = [255, 255, 255, 255]

    def __init__(self, x_coord, y_coord, x2_coord, y2_coord, color):
        self.x_coord = x_coord
        self.x2_coord = x2_coord
        self.y_coord = y_coord
        self.y2_coord = y2_coord
        self.color = color
        self.Line = pyglet.shapes.Line(x=self.x_coord, y=self.y_coord, x2=self.x2_coord, y2=self.y2_coord,
                                       color=self.color, width=5)

    @window.event
    def draw_line(self):
        return self.Line.draw()


ball = pyglet.shapes.Circle(x=0, y=0, radius=10, segments=10)
ball2 = pyglet.shapes.Circle(x=200, y=200, radius=10, segments=20)


def calculate_distance(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** 0.5


@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, symbol, modifiers):
    ball1_dst = calculate_distance(x, ball.x, y, ball.y)
    ball2_dst = calculate_distance(x, ball2.x, y, ball2.y)
    if ball1_dst > ball2_dst:
        line = DrawLines(x_coord=x, y_coord=y, x2_coord=ball2.x, y2_coord=ball2.y, color=[0, 255, 255, 255])
    else:
        line = DrawLines(x_coord=x, y_coord=y, x2_coord=ball.x, y2_coord=ball.y, color=[255, 0, 255, 255])

    line.draw_line()


@window.event
def on_draw():
    ball.x = window.width / 2
    ball.y = window.height / 2
    ball.draw()
    ball2.draw()


pyglet.app.run()
```

i want the `line.draw_line()` method in the on_draw() event but i have no idea how to.

I tried to create global variables for it.. didn't work..
I tried returning the values.. didn't work
I just want to be able to use the `line.draw_line()` method in the on_draw() event loop

Answer (score 0):

You must draw the lines in `on_draw` instead of `on_mouse_press`. Add a list of the lines:

```py
lines = []
```

Append each new line to the list:

```py
@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, symbol, modifiers):
    ball1_dst = calculate_distance(x, ball.x, y, ball.y)
    ball2_dst = calculate_distance(x, ball2.x, y, ball2.y)
    if ball1_dst > ball2_dst:
        line = DrawLines(x_coord=x, y_coord=y, x2_coord=ball2.x, y2_coord=ball2.y, color=[0, 255, 255, 255])
    else:
        line = DrawLines(x_coord=x, y_coord=y, x2_coord=ball.x, y2_coord=ball.y, color=[255, 0, 255, 255])
    lines.append(line)
```

Draw all the lines in the list in `on_draw`:

```py
@window.event
def on_draw():
    ball.x = window.width / 2
    ball.y = window.height / 2
    ball.draw()
    ball2.draw()
    for line in lines:
        line.draw_line()
```

---

However, the usual way to draw multiple related objects with Pyglet is to use a batch (see [class Batch](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/graphics/index.html#pyglet.graphics.Batch)):

```py
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=1900, height=1050, fullscreen=False, caption="Dots", resizable=True, vsync=True)

class DrawLines:
    coordinates = [0, 0]
    color = [255, 255, 255, 255]

    def __init__(self, x_coord, y_coord, x2_coord, y2_coord, color, batch):
        self.x_coord = x_coord
        self.x2_coord = x2_coord
        self.y_coord = y_coord
        self.y2_coord = y2_coord
        self.color = color
        self.Line = pyglet.shapes.Line(x=self.x_coord, y=self.y_coord, x2=self.x2_coord, y2=self.y2_coord,
                                       color=self.color, width=5, batch = batch)

batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
ball = pyglet.shapes.Circle(x=0, y=0, radius=10, segments=10, batch=batch)
ball2 = pyglet.shapes.Circle(x=200, y=200, radius=10, segments=20, batch=batch)
lines = []

def calculate_distance(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** 0.5

@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, symbol, modifiers):
    ball1_dst = calculate_distance(x, ball.x, y, ball.y)
    ball2_dst = calculate_distance(x, ball2.x, y, ball2.y)
    if ball1_dst > ball2_dst:
        line = DrawLines(x_coord=x, y_coord=y, x2_coord=ball2.x, y2_coord=ball2.y, color=[0, 255, 255, 255], batch=batch)
    else:
        line = DrawLines(x_coord=x, y_coord=y, x2_coord=ball.x, y2_coord=ball.y, color=[255, 0, 255, 255], batch=batch)
    lines.append(line)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    ball.x = window.width / 2
    ball.y = window.height / 2
    batch.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```